# SQL Query for Order Status report from Oracle DB

Tags: java, database, oracle, database-administration

I have a table Order_Status in Oracle DB 11, which stores order id and all its status for ex   ample

```
order id    status                  date
100         at warehouse            01/01/18
100         dispatched              02/01/18
100         shipped                 03/01/18
100         at customer doorstep    04/01/18
100         delivered               05/01/18
```

a few days back some of the orders were stuck in warehouse but it is not possible to check status of each order every day so no one noticed until we received a big escalation mail from business which arouse the requirement of a system or daily report which will tell us about status of all the order along with there present status and with some condition like if there are more than 2 days and no new status has been updated in DB for the order then mark it in red or highlight it.

we already have cron scheduled some of our reports but even if a create a SQL query for the status report it won't highlight pending order.

Note:- SQL, Java or some other tool suggestions both are welcome but SQL preferred then Tool then java.

Comment: So, lets say for example order id 100 has status at warehouse for 2 consecutive days then you need to highlight report..is it the case?

Comment: Show us your expected output for the sample data you've shown. Please cover all scenarios you can think of in the sample to avoid confusion. Also, do let us know the query you have tried so far by posting that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your requirement is "status will always change in every 2 days, if not there is something wrong"

```
select * from (    
    select order_id, 
               status, 
               update_date, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY update_date DESC) as rank 
        from Order_Status 
        where status != 'delivered'   
)
where update_date < sysdate - 2 and rank = 1
```

Comment: Please don't answer a question if your answer requires major assumptions.  The correct response is to post a comment asking for clarification.  You cannot comment yet, so please choose to answer questions that are on-topic and can actually be answered.  Please read [answer].

Comment: @joe thanks, you saved my day, result is perfect but threre is 1 small probleam, data is coming in the sql format 
`order id    status             date
100         at warehouse    01/01/18
100         dispatched        02/01/18
100         shipped             03/01/18
100         delivered           05/01/18`

is there any way to convert it into rows
order id     at warehouse     dispatched     shipped      delivered
100              01/01/18            02/01/18      03/01/18     04/01/18

and highlight those order which have more then 2 days delay or if there is any tool for this.

Comment: Yes you can do that, what you are looking for is rows to columns. You want to conver the rows for an order to be in the format of only one row, with 5 status column. Am I right?

Comment: Here is the SQL you are looking for         `select order_id,
           max(decode(t.status, 'at warehouse', update_date,null)) as at_warehouse_date, 
           max(decode(t.status, 'dispatched', update_date,null)) as dispatched_date, 
           max(decode(t.status, 'shipped', update_date,null)) as shipped_date, 
           max(decode(t.status, 'at customer doorstep', update_date,null)) as at_customer_doorstep_date, 
           max(decode(t.status, 'delivered', update_date,null)) as delivered_date
    from Order_Status
    group by order_id`

Comment: Hi @JOEDAI query is absolutely perfect, i added rest of my required fields to create report and it worked fine but now i am struct at the end, it would be great if you could help me,
1- along all these colums i need count of the stautus where order status is 'RESCHEDULED' in other words we can say it as number of delivery attempts before acutual delivery 
2- how can i find the difference between update_date of same order id when its status was "CREATED" and now its "DELIVERED" or we can say the time gap between created and delivered order.

Comment: hi @JOEDAI any help?

Comment: 1. When it is RESCHEDULED, does it add another record to the table? In that case, you can simply select count(*) group by order_status 2. You can simply use DELIVERED_date - CREATED_date to get the gap, can't you?  There are a lot of requirements there it seems, you have to work out your workflow and what the report looks like first. Maybe post the final report that you want to show in the UI, makes it easier.